# Excel macro search for word on sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This is an easy one, but I can't get it to work. I need to search for the word "Tons" on a sheet.

```
Sub findText()

If Cells.Find(What:="Tons", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate = True Then
MsgBox "Word Found"
Else
MsgBox "Word Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

I get the error "Object variable or With Block variable not set". My code works whenever the word "Tons" is on a sheet but comes back with an error whenever it is not. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: This thing with .Activate and true at the end of the .Find is wrong. Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
Sub findText()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Cells.Find(What:="Tons", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Word Found"
Else
    MsgBox "Word Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

*Try to create a `Range` and then test if you succeeded.*